# Compare model accuracy when training with imbalanced and balanced data

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, multiclass-classification, accuracy

So I was recently doing a data science project which is a multi class classification.
The project can be found https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge.

The dataset is an imbalanced dataset with 93 features and 9 possible outcomes (targets).

Since we don't know what any of these features are we don't know what kind of categories the targets represent I am not sure if balancing the data before training the model makes sense.

Therefore I just trained each of my test models with both, once with a balanced and once with an imbalanced dataset.

In particular this is what I did:

1. do a simple 80/20 split for training and test to create an imbalanced data and training set

```
index <- createDataPartition(data$target, p=.8, list=FALSE,times=1)
training <- data[index,]
test <- data[-index,]
```

2. downsample the training split and use it to create a downsampled training set and use the rest of the data for testing

```
training.downsampled <- downSample(training[,-ncol(training)],y=training$target,yname="target")
test.downsampled <-subset(data, !(id %in% training.downsampled$id))
```

So now to come to my main question. If I now train a model, for example a random forest, can I use the accuracies of both to compare if the model delivers a better accuracy while using balanced data?
I am concerned since I test against more data for the balanced one. If I can't compare it like this, then what would be a suitable method to achieve comparison of the both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accuracy is the worst metric you could use for an imbalanced dataset. If you choose accuracy as a metric when you have class imbalance, you will get very high accuracy. This is because the majority class has a higher frequency (or has more number of records) and hence the model will predict the majority class as the prediction majority of the time.

The metric you choose depends on what kind of dataset you have. If your data has class imbalance, you can go for F1 score, AUC score, True positive/True negative rate. They will give a more realistic score rather than accuracy.

Another point to remember is that if you want to balance your dataset, never use downsampling as it results in data loss which is a **BIG NO NO**. Always use  oversampling.

A word of caution though. Some experts believe that undersampling or oversampling is not the way to go when dealing with imbalance. Rather choosing the right metric is enough to deal with it. But other experts say that SMOTE is the way to go. It depends on you on what you think is right although comparing models like you are doing is probably a safe bet.

Other than that you are correct in your procedure to compare both the models.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you input. So using the F1_value for both the imbalanced training and balanced training should work? So I could make a statement using the f1 for example to tell which option (balanced or imbalanced) produces a better output?

Comment: Yes you can. Also don't use undersampling to balance your data.

Comment: Harrell would argue that threshold-based metrics are problematic whether there is class imbalance or not [(1)](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/)[(2)](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/), and Kolassa would argue that accuracy is problematic when the class balance is even [(3)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274). Why not use something like log loss that directly measures the probabilistic predictions and does not care about class imbalance?

Comment: "*Always use oversampling*", this **is patently false**. There are valid cases for downsampling, eg when data contain irrelevant items, or not sufficiently informative items, it is a good choice to downsample since information contained in the rest data is increased.

Comment: @NikosM. Usually we downsample or upsample when we have class imbalance and the final data where the irrelevant info has been removed. Downsampling then can lead to loss of info

Comment: @Dave I think F1 score (preferably F1 micro)can be used when we have class imbalance along with some other metrics which include log loss.

Comment: @spectre, again this is wrong. Depending on reason for imbalance, downsampling can actually increase information. A sweeping statement like this  is wrong. It is not always the case. Plus upsampling can introduce artifacts and bias into the final data (which is as detrimental as  information loss). Also there are many imbalanced cases where no re-sampling is actually neeed. So which one to use depends on various factors.